# PostGres returning MemoryError for a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of shape (2183651, 127) and I want to store the dataframe onto PostGres, however I keep getting the following error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (127, 2183651) and data type object
```

My system is running on 8GB Ram, and I have Python 64-bit installed.

I am using the `'psql_insert_copy'` method to push my dataframe onto the database;

```
 def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
        # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
        dbapi_conn = conn.connection
        with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
            s_buf = StringIO()
            writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
            writer.writerows(data_iter)
            s_buf.seek(0)

            columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
            if table.schema:
                table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name)
            else:
                table_name = table.name

            sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(table_name, columns)
            cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)

    engine = create_engine(
        'postgresql://' + str(engine1[2]) + ':' + str(engine1[3]) + '@' + str(engine1[0]) + ':' + str(
            engine1[4]) + '/' + str(engine1[1]))
    df3.to_sql(tablename, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method=psql_insert_copy, schema='public')
```

However this fails, is this error because of my hardware specs and is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an iterator directly to copy_expert, rather than materializing the entire dataset into s_buf and passing that.  The iterator would need to return a properly formatted line of data in the csv format, so might need to be wrapped somehow to do that.